# Drag and Drop support for touch enabled devices for react-ui-tree

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add DnD support for touch enabled devices for [react-ui-tree](https://github.com/pqx/react-ui-tree) and it seems to be behaving weirdly. While dragging seems to start with ***touchmove*** event and stops abruptly. But if you pickup from the same position and move, then things seem to work. Here is the GIF file just to show that.

[image]

Observations so far:

- Seems react is somehow not happy with tree being modified with
  ***tree.move()*** inside ***drag()*** method.
- Seems react is somehow not happy with ***setState()***.
- When drag starts and suddenly stops, we see the page scrolls so guessing the event has stopped midway by
  react but not sure.

All my changes are in this repo https://github.com/venugopalkathavate/react-ui-tree.git if you want to check. NOTE this can be reproduced with Chrome dev tools.